# Remove groups from a CSV that contains folders and the list of people who has access

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have no idea what I am doing with powershell. I am still very new to scripting, and have always had trouble the few times I've had to use it.

At work I'm trying to clean up our shared directories that have individual permissions on them. I've have a CSV file that contains a list of directories, and any users & groups that have access to those directories.

The CSV file has information looking like this:

```
PATH       Identity
Folder1    AD\User1
Folder1    AD\Group1
Folder2    AD\User2
Folder2    AD\Group2
Folder3    AD\Group3
```

etc. It goes on similarly for about 1,800 entries. The problem is I need to filter any groups from this list and, if there are any folders that only have group access & no individual access then remove those from the list as well.

I was trying to make a new script to pull that csv into powershell & filter it, but no idea how to go about it.

I was trying this, but definitely don't think it's the right way to go about it:

```
$permissions = Import-csv C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\Permissions.csv | select Path,Identity | ft

$permissions | ForEach($_.Identity) {
$users Get-ADObject -Identity $_.Identity
if($users.ObjectClass -eq "user"){
select Path,Identity
}
}

Export-Csv C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\groupsRemoved.csv
```

Comment: Issue number 1 is that you pipe to `|ft` which is short for `|Format-Table`, and you store that in a variable. Only use `Format-Table` to display data to the screen. So step 1 is to remove `|ft` from the end of the first line.

Comment: It's a good attempt but unfortunately there are a lot of syntax errors here.  I would suggest looking over some of [these posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpowershell%5D+import+csv+get-aduser) for examples on how to go about this

Answer (score 0):

Not actually sure what you are attempting to do.

Seems like you want to save any of the shares that have user accounts instead of group accounts assigned.

This should do that.

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\Permissions.csv | Select Path, Identity

foreach($row in $csv){
    $user = $row.Identity
    $share = $row.Path
    if(Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -eq $user} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            User = $user
            Share = $share
        } | Export-Csv C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\groupsRemoved.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
    }
    else{
        Write-Host "$user is a Group"
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to get the permissions in real-time, you can do this.

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\Permissions.csv | Select Path
foreach($share in $csv){
    #Get list of users with permissions to share
    $shareUsers = (Get-SmbShareAccess -Name $share).AccountName
    
    foreach($user in $shareUsers){
        $user = ($user.Split('\'))[1]
        if(Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -eq $user} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                User = $user
                Share = $share
            } | Export-Csv C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\groupsRemoved.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
        }
        else{
            Write-Host "$user is a Group"
        }
    }
}
```